# Scala - Send Multiple Headers with scalaj.http.Http

Tags: java, scala, http, post, web

I am making a post request with the libraries listed below. It seems like my last header is being cut off. Ive tried the following two ways but neither seems to be working.

```
import scalaj.http._
import scalaj.http.Http


var result = Http("https://example.com" + Key + "/rowset")
  .postData(jsonOutput)
  .headers(Seq("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + accessToken)))
  .headers(Seq("content-Type" -> "application/json"))


var result = Http("https://example.com" + Key + "/rowset")
  .postData(jsonOutput)
  .headers(Seq("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + accessToken), "content-Type" -> "application/json"))
```

Comment: For some reason it works like this: var result = Http("example.com/v1/requestToken")
        .postForm
        .param("clientSecret", "XXXX")
        .param("clientId", "YYYY")

Answer (score 0):

Just to check; you are doing something with the result variable? It is still just a request and will remain so until you call i.e. result.asString which will execute the request and return the response (HttpResponse[String] in case of asString).